# Build error occurs after changing to SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I have an app code which was running successfully on iPhone SDK 3, but now I have changed to SDK 4.0 and the code gives error.

Here is the error:

[image]

And my frameworks are:

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: This question features images of text and does not feature enough information to resolve the problem. It needs a [mcve] - voting to close for now.

Answer (score 1):

Something's messed up about your development environment. I'm guessing you tried to install the 4.0 api over top of the 3?

No idea really specifically whats happened, but it's lost track of where its goods are. If I were you I'd reinstall a clean copy of XCode. Make sure you copy out your project folders, then delete your current install and put in a freshly downloaded one.

Comment: actually i bought a new mac with snow leopard already installed in it...and sold old one

Comment: Okay, well, a fresh XCode install ought to fix this. Or, at least, would be my first thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're building the iPhone target and it includes a Foundation.framework. From error messages you can see that it cannot find cocoa objects

Comment: sorry, foundation.framework, it has all the classes the linker complains about